# Angular 2 - cannot get base class instance with ViewChild nor ContentChild

Tags: angular

answer:

- dont use exportAs
- use @ViewChild('myContent') myContent; to get the instance of the parent class
- it will only work if the view is initialized, so better use ngAfterViewInit

---

this concerns inheritance !

```
base class (component)
    |
inherited class (component)
```

I have a base class component exported with exportAs

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-content',
    exportAs: 'myContent',
    ...
})
```

the inherited class component uses a reference to the base class template
in its own template

```
<my-content #myContent>
  ...
```

in the inherited component's code I try to get its instance

```
@ViewChild('myContent') myContent;
```

or

```
@ContentChild('myContent') myContent;
```

some say this should work but myContent is alway undefined

how do I solve this ?

thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the instance of the child component within the parent template you can use the Component class directly, without any references, like so

```
@ViewChild(MyComponentClass) myContent;
```

Where `MyComponentClass` is the exported name of the child component class.

As a side note, make sure that you are referenceing the `myComponent` variable after the views have been checked / initialized (using `ngAfterViewInit`) rather than on `ngOnInit`, since during the init stage, the child components would not have been created yet.

Here's a working plunkr :

https://plnkr.co/edit/Q53I4EIDOL0ZrUEo2jRN?p=preview

Comment: it's the other way around, I want to call the parent function from the child

Comment: I tried with ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit but still the reference in undefined

Comment: Fixed your plunkr to work.  Changed ContentChild to ViewChild, and removed the exportAs decleration.

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild(MyParentComponent) myParent:  MyParentComponent`

you can instance the Parent Component like `this.myParent`

plunker:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})

export class InheritedComponent extends BaseClassComponent {  

    @ViewChild(BaseClassComponent) myBaseclass: BaseClassComponent;

    doSomeOperations()
    {
        this.myBaseclass.toggle();
        console.log(this.visible); 
    }

}
```

Comment: then why calling the variable myChild ? it should be myParent or something.I tried your solution, it does not work

Comment: still the reference in undefined  ?

Comment: I'm getting True in console. UPDATED

Comment: you should get FALSE

I already tried that, does not work it gives UNDEFINED for the baseClass variable..

I updated the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/jjN9An8G2QKzqFqk3dnp?p=preview you can see for yourself

I tried in Chrome and Firefox